# View complete list of IntelliSense suggestions

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I need to refactor a project in Visual Studio 2017, that has ~100 code files, each code file has few problems with variable/proc names, which IntelliSense suggests to fix. Can I see a full list of IntelliSense suggestions and apply them all - for all files or for a single file?

Comment: Hi, we can find the intellisense errors in the Error List Window and use the filter to display the intellisense Only errors, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2017#error-list-filters

Comment: It doesnt show renaming suggestions for me, like that 'caption' is a property and it should be renamed to 'Caption'

Comment: Yes, the Error list not display the potential fixes for those intellisense error, you can try to report this suggestion to the VS Product Team in here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide